# How long does it take to optimize 1 tb disk?

Tags: windows-10

My pc's drive is optimizing since 2 hours. How long does it take? My drive's storage is 1 tb and I use windows 10. And can i stop this work while it is running? And can I disable this work for permanent and if I do so, will it harm my pc?

Comment: 1. Until it's finished, depending on fragmentation & the amount of free space on your drive. 2. Yes if you want, but wait for it to tell you it's stopped. 3. Why would you want to? It's doing it for a reason.

Comment: When it comes to defragmenting, [`Contig`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/contig) _(part of [SysInternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/))_ is a better defrag utility than Windows' stock `defrag`, and while there is a GUI for `contig` called [Power Defragmenter](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6462-power-defragmenter.html), it's latest update is 2yrs older than the most recent version of `contig`.

Answer (score 2):

If your computer has a hard drive 1 TB in size, 2 hours is within reason for a 7200-rpm hard drive. A 5400-rpm hard drive could take longer.

I would let it finish.

If you stop it, the defragment app will stop in an orderly fashion and nothing will be damaged.

> can I disable this work for permanent?

Yes you can. You will not harm the disk, but it will get slower and slower

You should set Optimize (Defrag for HDD) to Automatic, let it run itself and not try to run manually. Windows 10 Defrag does a very good job left on Automatic.

Automatic is the best way.